# "php_connect_nonb() failed: No error (0)"

Tags: php, ftp, vsftpd

I need to send files to my ftp server(vsftpd) via php. When i call function `print_r(error_get_last());` after `ftp_put()` i can see:

```
Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: No error (0)
Warning: ftp_put(): Switching to Binary mode.
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded
```

And files not sending.

Here is my vsftpd config. I also have opened 20,21,990,4000-5000 ports:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=NO
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
```

My php upload script:

```
public function upload($file, $path, $fileName){
        global $ftp_config;

        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_config['host']);
        if($conn_id)
        {
            $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_config['username'], $ftp_config['password']);
            ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

            print_r('/'.$path.''.$fileName);

            $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, '/'.$path.''.$fileName, $file, FTP_IMAGE);
            print_r(error_get_last());
            return $upload;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In other hand its easy to send the same files with FileZilla.

Have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved problem.

My FTP client was behind NAT, so i just add `pasv_address=[your_ip]` in my `vsftpd.conf`